# How to filter a dictionary of key value with an array of keys in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

```
var allOptions = [
    {value: 'AA', key: 'a'},
    {value: 'BB', key: 'b'},
    {value: 'CC', key: 'c'},
    {value: 'DD', key: 'd'},
    {value: 'EE', key: 'e'}
];

var selected = ['a', 'c'];
```

I want to get objects from `allOptions` which have keys in variable array `selected`

i.e I want result as

```
[
    {value: 'AA', key: 'a'},
    {value: 'CC', key: 'c'},
];
```

Any suggestions appreciated if not involving jquery.

Comment: does [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) not work for you?

Comment: that worked, I am new to JS and my mistake, similar questions are available, but since I can't delete question, appreciate your response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `includes` in filter and comparing the array item with the `key` object.

```js
var allOptions = [{
    value: 'AA',
    key: 'a'
  },
  {
    value: 'BB',
    key: 'b'
  },
  {
    value: 'CC',
    key: 'c'
  },
  {
    value: 'DD',
    key: 'd'
  },
  {
    value: 'EE',
    key: 'e'
  }
];

var selected = ['a', 'c'];

const res = allOptions.filter(({
  key
}) => selected.includes(key));

console.log(res)
```